# discord.py How to show user level system including new members

Tags: discord.py

I've made a code for showing level that works perfectly fine except that when new members join the code doesn't work because it only takes information of whats already in the .json file. I want to make it so that when new members join their level appears too.

```
#THE LEVEL SYSTEM ITSELF 
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open(r"C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\BOTZS\test.py", 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)

  await update_data(users, member)

  with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot == False:
      with open('LvlUP.json', 'r') as f:
          users = json.load(f)

      await update_data(users, message.author)
      await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
      await level_up(users, message.author, message)

      with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
          json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
  if not f'{user.id}' in users:
      users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
      users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
      users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
  users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, message):
  experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
  lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
  if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      embed = discord.Embed(title="**LEVEL UP!**",description=f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}! :fire: 'f'\n Soundwave Superior,{user.mention} Inferior ',color=discord.Color.dark_red())
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
      users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
      await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

#MY CODE
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   global m
   with open(r"C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\BOTZS\LvlUP.json", 'r') as f:
       m = json.load(f)
   if message.content == "Level":
       embed=discord.Embed(title="**Current Level**", description=(str(m[str(message.author.id)]["level"])),color=discord.Color.dark_red())
       await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the file you open when a member joins the correct file? It's not a json file?

Comment: well I actually dont have a separate file for when members join, I only have a .json file for the level system

Comment: I notice you have two `on_message` events.  Only the second one will actually get used.  You should combine your two `on_message` events into one function.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't realize, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you didn't used the `on_member_remove` event. It would allow you to remove users when they leave your discord server. Also, I think you code could be a bit lighter and more understandable.

Here's a way to make a very simple level system for your bot :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

from json import dumps, loads
from random import randint

def get_data():
    with open('members.json', 'r') as file:
        return loads(file.read())

def set_data(members):
    with open('members.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(dumps(members, indent=2))

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    members = self.get_data()
    members.append({'name': member.name, 'id': member.id, 'level': 0,'xp': 0})
    set_data(members)
    
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(self, member):
    members = self.get_data()
    members.remove({'name': member.name, 'id': member.id, 'level': member.level, 'xp': member.xp})
    set_data(members)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    members = self.get_data()
    member = members[message.author.id]
    member['xp'] += 5
    if member['xp'] > member['xp']**(1 / 4):
        member['level'] += 1
        await message.channel.send(f" {message.author.mention} leveled up! He's now level {member['level']}")
        set_data(members)

@commands.command()
async def xp(self, ctx):
    members = self.get_data()
    for member in members:
        if ctx.author.id == member['id']:
            await ctx.send(f"️ You're level {member['level']} ({member['xp']}/{self.base_xp * (member['level']+1 * self.factor)})")
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!